# Difficult equations with fractions and variables

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, math-history

i tried but i'm stuck it seems too difficult for me

why is this even true? please. help me.

*For any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$*
$$ \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{\sin(\alpha+ 2\pi p / n) }{x^2-2\cos(\alpha+2\pi p/n)xy + y^2} = \frac{\sin(\alpha) x^{n-1}y^{n-1}}{x^{2n}-2x^ny^n \cos(\alpha) + y^{2n}} $$

Comment: Hint: you can integrate both members on $\alpha$ and the LHS is the logarithm of the product of the denominators. You can factor these as $(x-e^{i\theta}y)(x-e^{-i\theta}y)$. To simplify, WLOG $y=1$. You can try the Vieta's relation to evaluate the products.

Comment: Could you provide elementary solution